# Joomla Calendar format not displaying the correct format

Tags: joomla-3.x, form-fields-types, calendar

Below is my calendar field in the form

```
        <field name="job_next_run_date_time" 
        type="calendar" 
        label="JSCH_JOBV_NEXT_DATE_TIME"
        description="JSCH_JOBV_NEXT_DATE_TIME_DESC"
        format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%I:%S"
        readonly="readonly"
        class="readonly" />
```

In database the  value is stored for the field as below

```
2020-05-19 15:05:00
```

But on the screen I am rendering using the code

```
echo $this->form->renderField('job_next_run_date_time');
```

and it is displaying as below

```
2020-05-19 03:03:00
```

Why the hours part is not shown in 24 hours and minute part is changed from 05 to 03?

When changed the calendar field to a normal text field it displayed correctly as below

```
2020-05-19 15:05:00
```

On further investigation on the core Joomla library I found the below piece of code in `\libraries\joomla\form\fields\calendar.php`.  I added an echo statement before and after.

```
echo $this->value;  //malai this prints 2020-05-19 15:05:00
$tz = date_default_timezone_get();
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$this->value = strftime($this->format, strtotime($this->value));
date_default_timezone_set($tz);
echo $this->value;  //malai this prints 2020-05-19 15:03:00
```

Does this gives any clue???

Comment: What if you try to set the field attribute: `timeformat="24"`. I'm not sure since this should be the default value on this but maybe it can help. I do not have any clue about the altered minutes though, I've never seen that behavior at calendar field.

Comment: @Zollie no `timeformat="24"` dont have any effect.

Comment: Do you feed the Calendar field with pre-formatted `date` object or you just take the date directly from the database?

Comment: @Zollie it is directly from the database.  In database it is a datetime data type (mysql)

Comment: I would try with creating a `JDate` object from the data with one or two extra lines of code like `$date = new Date('2012-12-1 15:20:00');` and see if it helps or not... Link: https://docs.joomla.org/How_to_use_JDate

Comment: I mean with using the `JDate` object at least you could see if the issues are there or not and it is caused inside calendar field or before...

Comment: Ohh, in the meantime I see that Arlen suggested you two other attributes to set and it helped, so it looks like that it is getting to the solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try this:

Drop the format line completely from the xml definition. In its place try:

```
translateformat="true"
showtime="true"
```

and see what that gives you.

My guess here is the system is ignoring the time section of your format string because you haven't told it that the calendar field should include a time (the showtime parameter). I also think the time section of your format string is incorrect, but it's not telling you that because you haven't told it to use it, so setting translateformat to true without having a format string should test that guess without adding issues caused if I'm correct about the format string.

If making those two changes results in a better time display, feel free to test my suspicions of the format string by restoring your original format string to the definition, and either setting translateformat to false or removing it entirely (default value for this param is false, so either action will do) and see what happens.

Comment: after adding these attributes, now I am seeing the correct time in 24 hours format with proper minutes and seconds as stored in the database.  I tried various other combinations and nothing worked.  Worked only when both are true and that is ignoring the format given.  You mentioned the time section is incorrect, what do you mean by that?

Comment: Lowercase i and s, as detailed here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php If you want to test different format strings, then don't forget to set translateformat to false.

Answer (score 0):

Your `%I` should be `%i`, as per the [php docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) you are setting a boolean value (`Whether or not the date is in daylight saving time - 1 if Daylight Saving Time, 0 otherwise`) in the middle of the datestring. I assume you were probably looking for lowercase `i`, which is minutes with leading zeros.

Comment: No, `%i` displays nothing.  The field becomes empty.

Comment: @Malaiselvan try `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S` as the format.